# Choose all of the options—tables, views, and stored procedures

Tags: entity-framework

The Entity Data Model Wizard shows up and you now can use this to query your database and generate the model diagram.

My question is that should I choose all of the options—tables, views, and stored procedures?
I don't know what tables/stored procedures will be used. If I select all and database is big, how it affects the performance?

And I may add new stored procedures in the future, in this situation. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose what you need to start with.

If you need more later, you can right click on the diagram, and choose Update Model from Database, and add more, or refresh existing, or remove elements.